# How do i fix an expected indented block in python

Tags: python

python says i have to fix some indent in the "class OBstaclesManager" line, it says expected indented block. what do i fix

```
class ObstaclesManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obstacles_list = []

    def generateobstacles(self):
        can_gen = True
        for obstacle in self.obstacles_list:
            if obstacle.x > win_w*0.75:
                can_gen = False
```

Comment: The indentation looks good here. please post the complete stack trace

Comment: sometimes you use combination of tab and white-space that might creates issues

Comment: Check for the use of tabs and whitespaces, also check the indentation of your code after this class if it exists.

Comment: you can copy paste the block from your question and use it, looks clean :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use cat to distingusih tabs and spaces

this command shows tabs as '^I'

```
cat -A myfile
```